# Adding a parameter into a php function

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php function which is :

```
function omv_get_pages($manga, $chapter) {
    global $omv_img_types;
    $pages = array();

    $dirname = "mangas/$manga/$chapter/";
    $dir = @opendir($dirname);
    if ($dir) {
        while (($file = @readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            if (!is_dir($dirname . $file . '/')) {
                $file_extension = strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, ".") + 1));
                if (in_array($file_extension, $omv_img_types)) {
                    $pages[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        @closedir($dir);
    }

    sort($pages);

    return $pages;
}
```

This is a function of a manga reader php script, and it generates the chapter pages.

The problem I have, is this function generates the number of pages just as the number of the chapter page (images), but I want to add a comments page in the last of every chapter.

I won't use a comment script from scratch, I'll just use Disqus solution, but the problem I've tried many things to add it, but nothing works for me, maybe I'll call the comments page from a file or any thing.

If any one have an idea to help I really appreciate it because I need it so much, and thanks to all.

Comment: Where is the professionals guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it work for you to pass in the comment page as a parameter and then add it too the end of the array? For example:

```
function omv_get_pages($manga, $chapter, $commentPage) {
    global $omv_img_types;
    $pages = array();

    $dirname = "mangas/$manga/$chapter/";
    $dir = @opendir($dirname);
    if ($dir) {
        while (($file = @readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            if (!is_dir($dirname . $file . '/')) {
                $file_extension = strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, ".") + 1));
                if (in_array($file_extension, $omv_img_types)) {
                    $pages[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        @closedir($dir);
    }

    sort($pages);

    $pages[] = $commentPage;

    return $pages;
}
```

Comment: When adding the parameter on the end of the array as your example would it be added to the end of the chapter?

Comment: @Saif Lacrimosa Yes It would be the last element which should put it at the end of the chapter

Comment: I'll try it my friend and I'll see it, I really appreciate it

Comment: yes the last page was created but it is empty and here is the $commentPage variable how I made it : http://i933.photobucket.com/albums/ad177/rsm23/comment_zpsb21deca7.png

Comment: @Saif Lacrimosa Your Variable looks fine, I would have to see the code where this was called and how you used the $pages array to debug further.

Comment: This is the function file : http://pastebin.com/c4j5V4qu and this is the comments file : http://pastebin.com/Yv6KHz9x

Comment: I don't see where do are calling it and using the result. The functions look fine.

Comment: yes, but the comments page is empty look : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2keUK5KhVo8RHBsNzFVM3lsMkk/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I get it but I don't see where your calling the function or using the result.

Comment: All the functions are used and called in one file "index.php" : http://pastebin.com/zLw8MxXH

Comment: on line 74 $pages = omv_get_pages($manga, $chapter["folder"]); you need to pass in your $commentPage variable.

Comment: No, problem brother, I just need fix this problem, and thank you for everything till now!

Comment: on line 74 $pages = omv_get_pages($manga, $chapter["folder"]); you need to pass in your $commentPage variable.

Comment: What about the line 74?

Comment: I've done it : $pages = omv_get_pages($manga, $chapter["folder"], $commentPage); but still the same problem brother, please help me, and I apologies to you for all those problems

Comment: Your function call on line 74 wants you to pass in the third parameter In other words the function is never getting the $commentPage variable and it needs it to put content on your comment page

Comment: So What I have to do my friend?

Comment: I can't tell if the file you are defining $commentPage on is included or not. But if it wasn't Your comment page would be blank.

Comment: do you mean to require it on the index.php file : require_once("comments.php");?

Comment: yes exactly and make sure it's defined as global ie:( global $commentPage;)

Comment: Brother look at this problem, it is calling it as an image : http://i933.photobucket.com/albums/ad177/rsm23/comments_zpsf462cdf7.png

Comment: your putting it in img tags on line 207-210 and echoing it on line 217 or close to that those are the line numbers on the version you put up on http://pastebin.com/zLw8MxXH

Comment: yes I was thinking on that, those lines are important to show the chapter pages, I'm thinking in a way, to tell the script, if you reaches the last page, remove the "img" tag

Comment: Thanks my fired, it has been solved, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've made it clear what exactly you need. Do you mean that you wish to add the comments page in the middle of the function? Or that you simply wish to add an empty element to the $pages array every time you reach the end of one of the chapter directories?

Comment: yes, exactly what you've said in the second instruction I wish to add an empty element to the $pages array every time you reach the end of one of the chapter directories